# Animation with mvvm light on windows phone 7

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, windows-phone-7, mvvm-light

I have an intriguing question.
Let's say I want to play an animation or change the visual state etc of my view FROM THE VIEW MODEL.
How can I do that?
Its for building an MVVM application on windows phone 7.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the [MVVM Light Toolkit's Messenger class](http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2009/09/27/mvvm-light-toolkit-messenger-v2-beta.aspx): your view-model would send messages such as "play animation" and "change visual state" when appropriate, and your view's code-behind would register for these messages and react appropriately when they are sent.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for are "DataTriggers". This is a pain in the ass for WP7 because you have to rely on buggy 3rd party libraries to get this to work (ex: http://expressionblend.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Behaviors%20and%20Effects&referringTitle=Documentation abandonware?)

Silverlight 4 has this built in so there is light at the end of the tunnel but it's gonna take a while for WP7.